# Maven multimodule project with different spring boot versions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

Currently I have a multimodule project with 4 submodules and all of these use Spring 3. I am setting the spring version in the parent pom using

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

I want to add a new submodule to this project but I want that to have a different spring boot version. How can I do that?

Comment: Simple question: Why? Also I would suggest to upgrade to most recent one (3.2.3)... and keep up-to-date... Are those module stand-alone SB apps?

Comment: @khmarbaise One of my submodules use Apache Solr which doesn't support Spring 3.x so I have to use Spring 2.x there. Each of my submodules are seperate services and they communicate to each other. Since my services are not that big I decided to keep them under a single parent module.

Comment: There are two things: Why having the solr part within the same multi module? (partially answered) If so you should change to use spring-boot-dependencies via depMgmt instead of using the spring-boot-starter-parent (implies inherit to all module). That means you can define to use the spring-boot-dependencies for one module and maybe another module without it.

Answer (score 0):

The only option I see is to remove the boot-parent from your parent and import the parent in the submodules.

```
grim@main:~/workspacesdf$ tree test
test
├── bar
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
├── foo
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
└── pom.xml
```

`foo/pom.xml` is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>test</groupId>
        <artifactId>test</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

and `bar/pom.xml` is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>test</groupId>
        <artifactId>test</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.14</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

And `pom.xml` is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>bar</module>
        <module>foo</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Comment: In your root pom you should define plugin versions etc. via pluginManagement...

Comment: Yes, I could place both dependencyManagement-xmlnodes in the root-pom.xml and specify the version using a parameter. I decided to use this bare unoptimized version as my answer in order to keep it simple.

Comment: There is a secodn reason I just imagin by myself. Since both services are bound in one parent-pom the context of the "project" might be similar and its possible that same java-logic and java-dtos might share across the module Foo and Bar in another module "**Commons**". In order to extract those logic into a library without springboot-version-dependency I did not placed spring inheritedly in the parent-pom.xml.